# how to use components dont knowed by another (compose components)?

Tags: angular

I want to create a *generic component* that use another components but the *generic component* does not have direct reference to this components.

In other words, suppose a *List* component that draws a list of *ListRow* components, but a component that use the *List* wants to use a specific list row, for example, *MyCustomListRow* (that extends *ListRow*) .

This *MyCustomListRow* has a specific html template, so, how can I tell to *List* component to use *MyCustomListRow* without know specifics list rows like *MyCustomListRow*?

An example of code can be found here [http://plnkr.co/edit/GAsf0NGy5Dx7OC9lMGLD?p=preview]

The wanted result is a list of MyCustomListRow, something like

- this is MyCustomListRow  :)
- this is MyCustomListRow  :)
- this is MyCustomListRow  :)

But I get

- [object Object]
- [object Object]
- [object Object]

or with little code modifications

- this is a ListRow  :(
- this is a ListRow  :(
- this is a ListRow  :(

### List

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list',
    properties: [
        'listRows: list-rows'
    ]
})

@View({
    template: `
      <ul>
          <li *ng-for="#item of listRows">
              <listRow >{{item}}</listRow>
              <input type="button" value="..." />
          </li>
      </ul>
    `,
    directives: [NgFor ] // , bind(ListRow).toFactory(ListBindingManager.ListRowFactory)
})


export class List {
    listRows: ListRow[];    

    constructor() {
        this.listRows = [];

    }
}
```

### ListRow

```
@Component({
    selector: 'listRow '
})
@View({
    template: 'this is a ListRow  :( '
})

export class ListRow {
    constructor() {
    }

}
```

### MyCustomListRow

```
@Component({
    selector: 'listRow'
})
    @View({
        template: 'this is MyCustomListRow  :)   '
})
export class MyCustomListRow extends ListRow {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

### App (using the list)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  bindings: [ListBindingManager]
})
@View({
  template: `
    <list [list-rows]="myRows" >
    </list>
  `,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, List]
})
export class App {
  myRows: MyCustomListRow[];
  constructor() {
    ListBindingManager.listRowBindings = MyCustomListRow;

    this.myRows = [];
    this.myRows.push(new MyCustomListRow());
    this.myRows.push(new MyCustomListRow());
    this.myRows.push(new MyCustomListRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be confusing things a bit. `{{item}}` is for text interpolation. Angular doesn't know how to print `MyCustomListRow` objects. See my [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/x8admafNuKRO2Xewy0KG?p=preview).

Comment: ok, but I want to use a complex template for MyCustomListRow (maybe with some other components) , so, a simple string property is not enough.